# Shell script: shorten or aliasing an address after a command

Tags: shell, scp, bash

I want to abbreviate or set an alias to a destination address every time I use while copying files. For example,

```
scp <myfile> my_destination
```

where `my_destination` could be `hbaromega@192.168.1.100:Documents`.  So I want to modify my .bash_profile by inserting something like

```
alias my_destination = 'hbaromega@192.168.1.100:Documents' .
```

But that doesn't work since `my_destination` is not a command.

Is there a way out?

Note: I don't want to abbreviate the whole command, but only the address, so that I can use it with other possible commands.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do what you want for the reason you state (an alias defines an entire command). But you could use a shell function to come close:

```
my_scp() {
  scp "$@" hbaromega@192.168.1.100:Documents/.
}
```

which you could then call as

```
my_scp *.c
```

(Using $@ in doublequotes is shell black magic that avoids trouble if any of the file names matched by the *.c glob contain spaces)

Of course, if you don't want to define a function, you could always use a shell variable to at least save the retyping:

```
dest='hbaromega@192.168.1.100:Documents/.'
scp *.c $dest
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options. You can set hostname aliases in your `~/.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host my_destination
  Hostname 192.168.1.100
  User hbaromega
```

You could use it like this:

```
$ scp myfile my_destination:Documents/
```

Note that you'd still have to specify the default directory.

Another option would be to just put an environment variable in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export my_destination='hbaromega@192.168.1.100:Documents/'
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
$ scp myfile $my_destination
```

BertD's approach of defining a function would also work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works without using `export` as well since anyway I am assigning a variable for the path or destination. So I can just put the following in my .basrc or .bash_profile :

```
my_destination='hbaromega@192.168.1.100:Documents/'
```

Then

```
scp <myfile> $my_destination
```

Similarly I can execute any action (e.g. moving a file)for any local destination or directory:

```
local_dest='/Users/hbaromega/Documents/'
```

and then

```
mv <myfile>  $local_dest
```

In summary, a destination address can be put as a variable, but not as a shell command or function.

Answer (score -1):

The reason it **does not work** is there are spaces surrounding the `=` sign. As pointed out, an alias must be called as the first part of the command string. You are more likely to get the results you need by exporting `my_destination` and then calling it with a `$`. In `~/.bashrc`:

```
export my_destination='hbaromega@192.168.1.100:Documents'
```

Then:

```
scp <myfile> $my_destination
```

**Note:** you will likely need to provide a full path to `Documents` in the export.

Comment: It wouldn't work anyways, because aliases can only be replaced if they're the first thing in a command.

Comment: Correct you are, perhaps an export --- fixed :)